# How to programmatically check mirror front camera switch on/off Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, camera, front-camera

Is it possible to turn off front camera mirror mode programmatically in iOS or how to check front camera switch on/off programmatically?

[image]

Comment: did you try to search before asking? [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=check+front+mirror+camera+is+on+or+off+swift&oq=check+front+mirror+camera+is+on+or+off+swift&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.10041j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @FahimParkar i need to do all operations programmatically in ios swift. Is it possible?

Comment: What you want to do? give example & I can help you with that...